# Why Am I Getting GHC Couldn't Match Type Error in Functor Instance?

Tags: haskell, ghc, functor

I am trying to write a Functor instance:

```
module TreeN where

data TreeN a = LeafN a | ParentN a [TreeN a] deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor TreeN where

fmap f (LeafN x) = LeafN (f x)
fmap f (ParentN x children) = (ParentN (f x) (TreeN.fmap f children))
```

And I get this Error:

```
src/TreeN.hs:7:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘TreeN t’ with ‘[TreeN t]’
      Expected type: (t -> a) -> [TreeN t] -> [TreeN a]
        Actual type: (t -> a) -> TreeN t -> TreeN a
    • Relevant bindings include
        fmap :: (t -> a) -> [TreeN t] -> [TreeN a]
          (bound at src/TreeN.hs:7:1)
  |
7 | fmap f (LeafN x) = LeafN (f x)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

It is a mystery to me why GHC thinks I want to wrap fmap's input and output in another layer of structure.

I also tried spelling out this:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

but that results in different errors. I cannot tell whether GHC is erroring out because it saw the same thing twice, or whether you are supposed to be explicit about this and being explicit about it exposes some other problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TreeN.fmap can only deal with a TreeN object, and instead you are passing a list named `children`.  You can ask the compiler to write the instance for you and look at what the compiler writes: `ghc -c -XDeriveFunctor -ddump-deriv  mytree.hs`

Comment: Beware of the indentation. The code you posted defines an _empty_ functor instance, and the defines an independent function `fmap` which is unrelated to the `fmap` method of the functor class. You need to indent the `fmap` definition more to make it part of the instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `parentN` has a *list* of `TreeN`s, so you need to perform a mapping over all children:

```
instance Functor TreeN where
    fmap f (LeafN x) = LeafN (f x)
    fmap f (ParentN x children) = ParentN (f x) (map (fmap f) children)
```

Your implementation of the `Functor` is however the "standard" implementation, you can make use of the [**`DeriveFunctor`** language extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor#derivefunctor) and work with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data TreeN a = LeafN a | ParentN a [TreeN a] deriving (Eq, Functor, Show)
```

Comment: Is there any comprehensive of language extensions?

Comment: Is there a similar way to derive Applicative, Monad, etc?

Comment: @JamesStrieter: this is a page that eventually links to all *GHC* language extensions https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts.html

Comment: @JamesStrieter: no since deriving an `Applicative` and `Monad` has no "trivial" solution. You can use [`DeriveVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html) if the data type simply contains an object that is an instance of `Applicable` and `Monad`. You can also derive `Foldable` and `Traversable` automatically.